# SSO samlv2 adfs pass through authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, office365, metadata, saml, adfs

Here's the situation :

1. Login page of my application (login(not a mail), password)
2. redirection to an adfs which ask me login/password of the machine.
3. the configured adfs redirect me (with a post) to my app and logged

I would like to know if it's possible to pass through the second step using information of the first login page.
For ADFS and for office365 azure AD.

Thanks for the future help !

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of ADFS is to outsource authentication.

This means that ADFS controls the login screen not the application.

This is important for security and also for SSO functionality.

If you want to pass credentials through you need the active profile (WCF) not the passive profile (browser).

Essentially, you are calling a WS-Trust endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

And what about adfs logout redirect ?
i found answer with wa=wsignout and wreply but not working
how configure it in adfs windows properties and in sp metadata ?